# Mapping $\mathbb R^n - \{0\}$ to $S^{n-1}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

How might one map $\mathbb R^n - \{0\}$ to $S^{n-1}$ ?

I found this in a primer on homology where it is proved that the to spaces are homotopy equivalent, as an example of removing a single point from two spaces in order to be able to distinguish them homologically.

Comment: Presumably, then, you don't just want any old map (like a constant map.) The basic such map is $$x\mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, of course, I need one that would be give an identity for S^(n-1) when composed with the inclusion map i: S^(n-1) -> R^n - {0}. That one works, thanks. I might think a little bit more next time before I bother people with dumb questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic such map is:

$$x\mapsto \frac x{\|x\|}$$

The homotopy is:

$$h(x,t)=\frac{x}{(1-t)+t\|x\|}$$